# SPSS Amos Binary Outcome - Model Fit

Tags: spss, binary-data, amos

I was just wondering if anybody could help me, I'm conducting a path analysis in SPSS Amos with a binary outcome. I've specified the variable as binary using Tools>Data Recode, I've then calculated the variable estimates using MCMC.

My question is: how do I know calculate overall model fit?

The model is as follows, with all variables except psychosis (binary) being continuous.

- Esteem    <---    Bullying
- Intrusion <---    Bullying
- Intrusion <---    Esteem
- PsychosisRisk <---    Intrusion
- PsychosisRisk <---    Bullying

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you add more details about your data & your model here, maybe paste in some output? I doubt this question is answerable at present.

Comment: Hello, Yes of course - I have 4 variables. Bullying (continuous), Self-Esteem (Continuous), Intrusive Thoughts (Cont.) and Psychosis Risk (Binary). The following model is being tested: Bullying -> Psychosis Risk, Bullying -> Esteem, Bullying -> Intrusion, Esteem ->, Intrusion->Psychosis Risk.

Comment: Doesn't Amos give you any fit indices like Chi², CFI, RMSEA, SRMR, etc.? I'd expect it to do that automatically when fitting any SEM...

Comment: Unfortunately it appears not to calculate those for models containing a dichotomous outcome.

Comment: did you run Bayesian analysis ? there is a way you can do it - let me find the link for a PPT which shows how to calculate R-square I am working on similar problem - I want to know if your outcome is

Comment: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.structuralequations.com%2Fresources%2FMCMC_estimation_March30_2009.pps&ei=QpagVYGWJoXnoASfmZCwCA&usg=AFQjCNEBfA8YrKW02QMWyvoas3bVKN9jdA&bvm=bv.97653015,d.aWw